# Does a Keyboard give some kind of a trigger? My TableLayout is only updating when keyboard is showing

Tags: android, keyboard, tablelayout

I am developing an Android application. The application is about a chess game. The user can put in the width and height of the chess board by a AlertDialog.Builder. The weird thing is: when the OK button is clicked, while the keyboard is still showing, the chessboard is perfectly updating. But when clicking OK when the keyboard is not showing, the chessboard is not updating. The chessboard is a tablelayout. The rows are created programmatically. I will demonstrate the problem in pictures:

This is the AlertDialog.Builder without showing keyboard:

[image: This is the AlertDialog.Builder without showing keyboard]

The result is that the TableLayout shows nothing:

[image: The result is that the TableLayout shows nothing]

This is the AlertDialog.Builder that is showing keyboard:

[image: This is the AlertDialog.Builder that is showing keyboard]

And the TableLayout is showing perfectly now:

[image: And the TableLayout is showing perfectly]

This is the custom tablerow class:

```
public class TableRowChess extends TableRow {

private Context context;

private int numberOfColumns;
private int rowNumber;

private String[][] solution;

public TableRowChess(Context context, int numberOfColumns, int rowNumber, String[][] solution) {
    super(context);

    this.context = context;
    this.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
    this.rowNumber = rowNumber;
    this.solution = solution;

    initializeTableRow();
    initializeTextViews();
}


private void initializeTableRow(){
    this.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (float) numberOfColumns));
}

private void initializeTextViews(){
    TableRow.LayoutParams  params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i ++){
        SquareTextView tv = new SquareTextView(context);

        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setBackgroundResource(getCorrectBackground(i));
        tv.setHeight(tv.getLayoutParams().width);
        tv.setText(solution[rowNumber][i]);
        tv.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        this.addView(tv);
    }
}

private int getCorrectBackground(int columnNumber){
    if((rowNumber % 2) == 0){
        if((columnNumber % 2) == 0){
            return R.drawable.square_white;
        } else {
            return R.drawable.square_brown;
        }
    } else {
        if((columnNumber % 2) == 0){
            return R.drawable.square_brown;
        } else {
            return R.drawable.square_white;
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the code that is being called when the OK button is clicked:

```
private void setupChessBoard(){
    tableLayout.removeAllViews();

    String[][] solution = new Algorithm(dimensionsDialog.getHeight(), dimensionsDialog.getWidth(), dimensionsDialog.getNumberOfQueens(), dimensionsDialog.getNumberOfBishops()).getSolution();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < dimensionsDialog.getHeight(); i ++){
        tableLayout.addView(new TableRowChess(this, dimensionsDialog.getWidth(), i, solution));
    }
}
```

I do not understand why the code works when the keyboard is showing and why it does not work when it is not showing. I do not see the relation here? Or is there something wrong in the code?

I hope someone can help me! Thanks.